# Sound balance issue windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio

This is an issue I've run into before. I had sound in both headphones but recently had to shift my system around. I unplugged my headphones and when I plugged them back in I ran into the first issue. I could hear music but I couldn't hear voices on any media. Another super user thread said to adjust sound balance which I did, restoring voices to my sound. However, my current issue is that when I go to game I lose hearing in the balance area (right side) that I decreased to regain voices. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The only way I've fixed this is to reset windows.

Thanks